# End function if $thisPage equals specific page

Tags: javascript, php

I'd like to prevent a function from running on certain pages. For example, I put `<?php $thisPage="services"; ?>` on the top of my Services page and the code below in my script.js. I try to exit using `return;` but this just breaks everything on all pages. Seems so straight forward, Why doesn't this work?

```
$(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
var self = $(this),
height = self.height(),
top = self.scrollTop();

// ** Stop this code from running on the services page **
if ($thisPage=="services") {
  return;
}

// but keep running on all other pages
if (($(window).width() >= 550) && ($(this).scrollTop() > 550)) {

  $('nav#menu').fadeIn(500);
} else if (($(window).width() >= 550) && ($(this).scrollTop() < 550)) {
  $('nav#menu').fadeOut(500);
} else {
  $('nav#menu').hide();
}

});
```

Comment: you need to show us the full PHP here and how it's implemented.

Answer (score 3):

looks like a mix of php and javascript but the php isn't within php tags so will not be executed. You could try and set the variable with php and then test in javascript.

```
<script>
    <?php
        echo "var page='$thisPage';";
    ?>
    $(window).on('scroll resize', function() {
        var self = $(this),
        height = self.height(),
        top = self.scrollTop();

        if( page=='services' ) return;

        // but keep running on all other pages
        if (($(window).width() >= 550) && ($(this).scrollTop() > 550)) {

          $('nav#menu').fadeIn(500);
        } else if (($(window).width() >= 550) && ($(this).scrollTop() < 550)) {
          $('nav#menu').fadeOut(500);
        } else {
          $('nav#menu').hide();
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're mixing PHP and JavaScript incorrectly here:

```
if ($thisPage=="services") {...
```

What you want to do is set a JavaScript variable using PHP when load the page:

```
<?php echo "var foo = $thisPage"; ?>
```

And then use `foo` in your JavaScript test:

```
if (foo=="services") {...
```